# Error with Reading Files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working through Learn Python the Hard Way but am having a problem with an exercise that reads a file: https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/ex15.html

I have followed this and made sure my file is in the same folder as my python file. I keep getting the error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex15.py", line 5, in <module>
    txt = open(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ex15_sample.txt'
```

I am entering: python ex15.py ex15_sample.txt into the powershell. I tried looking up the problem I'm having but could not find anything that helped in my case. Let me know if I am doing something wrong or if I'm missing something. Thanks

Comment: probably there is `No such file or directory: 'ex15_sample.txt'`

Comment: Try making sure you are running the program in the same directory as the text file or you will have to make the name of the textfile its filepath.

Comment: I have a text file named: ex15_sample.txt saved in the same folder as the python file. Doesn't that error occur when the file is not in the same location?

Comment: Adding onto Josh, you can also use the full filepath to get around this

Comment: The default location is the current directory of the process you are running, which is not necessarily the same directory that your python file is sitting in.

Comment: you may be executing the python interpreter from a different folder than your script (and text file) are located.

Comment: Ok, right. It works when I use the full file path. So am I just supposed to use this full path when reading files?

Comment: That's up to you, in practice it is often wise to do that, but it depends on how you want to run programs.

Comment: @JanoyCresva not specifically.. the method of executing from a particular location and using relative file locations is perfectly valid. You just need to make sure you're executing from where you think you are

Comment: @JanoyCresva are you using an IDE? sometimes they try to "help out" by silently switching around the working directory without letting you know. While IDE's are very helpful for many things, it's good to spend some time running code directly from a terminal or command prompt to get a feel for things like working directories, command line args, etc...

Comment: I'm running the file through the powershell. So if I'm understanding right, I'd have to have the text file and .py files in the same location as the rest of the python files?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your current path and whether your file exists by

```
import os

#get the current working directory
os.getcwd()

#check whether your file exists in the current working directory
os.path.exists("./ex15.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

try 2 things below

1. Check both files .py and .txt are at same location. and then execute program. 
   this is how i ran the code.

   C:\Users\db\Desktop\Python>python ex15.py
   enter File Name: ex15_sample.txt
   This is stuff I typed into a file.
   It is really cool stuff.
   Lots and lots of fun to have in here.
2. If your file is at other location you need to provide absolute path for your file. as

   C:\Users\db\Desktop\Python>python C:\Users\deepakb\Desktop\ex15_sample.txt

i had my txt file at desktop this time.

Answer (score 0):

A brief demonstration on working directory and relative file locations..

Say we have a text file named *hello.txt* with the contents:

```
Hello World!
```

that is located at "C:\Users\username\Documents\python\hello.txt"

And we have a python script named *script.py* with the contents:

```
with open('hello.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Which is located at "C:\Users\username\Documents\python\script.py"

If I just hit the windows key and type power shell and hit enter to open it, I'll see it by default gives me a prompt at my home directory: "C:\Users\username>". From here I can execute my python script by calling `C:\Users\username> python C:\Users\username\Documents\python\script.py`. If I do this, however, they python interpreter would have started in my home folder, and when it tries to find "hello.txt" it will only search through the folder "C:\Users\username". That's not where the file is, so we get a file not found error.

To resolve this we have a few options. Number one is to re-write our script file to include the full path of our text file: `... open("C:/Users/username/Documents/python/hello.txt", ...` This way there is no searching necessary, and the script can be run from anywhere. Another option is to change the working directory of the interpreter from within the script. You can set the working directory with the `os` library by calling `os.chdir('C:/Users/username/Documents/python')`. Finally you can set the working directory with PowerShell before calling the python interpreter using the `cd` command:

```
C:\Users\username> cd .\Documents\python\
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
It was a mistake from me naming the file as `ex15_sample.txt`.

When you are creating a file in notepad, the file name would be automatically `.txt`
so if you have created a file just rename it as `ex15_sample`.

or

You can also run the same program by giving `python ex15.py ex15_sample.txt.txt`

As you can see the file name might be `ex15_sample.txt` with a `.txt` extension.

Comment: Before give an answer, check the existing answer or comments. There is no problem with the extension as exposed on: `Ok, right. It works when I use the full file path. So am I just supposed to use this full path when reading files?`. Your collaboration is welcome, but it is not an answer to the previous question. If you are not sure, then add as comment.